# avconv frames option (avconv -r 1)

Tags: avconv

I'm new to this tool `avconv`

I want to extract 1 frame per second from the video, I'm using

```
avconv -i sample.avi -r 1 -s 200x200 -f image2 frames/foo-%03d.png
```

the `sample.avi` is of length `30` seconds, but the conversion gives output of `920` frames.

What to do? I want only `30` frames

Comment: It works for me...
Maybe try through mencoder instead of avconv.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify -vsync option.

I used to use following command to get a frame per second from a video file.

```
avconv -i video_file -f image2 -vsync 1 -r 1 %03d.png
```